# error de deployment

Tags: deployment, plesk

Quise subir una app en plesk y me tira este error, soy nueva programando, aunque googleé este error, no econtre solución.

> (1/1) FatalErrorException
>   Declaration of Symfony\Component\Translation\TranslatorInterface::setLocale($locale) must be compatible with Symfony\Contracts\Translation\LocaleAwareInterface::setLocale(string $locale)
>
> in TranslatorInterface.php line 24

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No estoy familiarizado con la herramienta. Pero consultado el [github de Symfony](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/34506). Dice que es error por diferencia de versiones de PHP. Verifica con `composer update`